# Combobox bound but does not show the values correctly

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I reached to bind a List in a combobox, but the display names are not correct. If I drop the list down, shows the items in an incorrect way. Let me show you:

[image: Combo 1]

But when I select the item, the property is showed correctly:

[image: Combo 2]

This is my model:

```
     class RouteModel : NotificationObject
        {
           #region Fields
            ...
            private string code;
            ...
            #endregion

            #region Properties
            ...
           public string Code
           {
            get { return code; }
            set
            {
                if (code != value)
                {
                    code = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Code);
                }
            }
        }
       ...
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
public PlanningViewModel()
        {

            _routesCollection = new List<RouteModel>();
            foreach (RouteModel route in GetRoutes())
                _routesCollection.Add(route);
        }


        private static TOPEntities _context;
        private List<RouteModel> _routesCollection;


        public List<RouteModel> RoutesCollection
        {
            get { return _routesCollection; }
            set
            {
                if (_routesCollection != value)
                {
                    _routesCollection = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => RoutesCollection);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<RouteModel> GetRoutes()
        {
            using (_context = new TOPEntities())
            {

                {
                    return _context.Routes.Select
                        (route => new RouteModel
                        {

                            Id_Route = route.Id_Route,
                            Code = route.Code,
                            MaxDepartTimeSB = route.MaxDepartTimeSB,
                            MaxDepartTimeDirect = route.MaxDepartTimeDirect,
                            Carrier_Id_Carrier = route.Carrier_Id_Carrier,
                            Address = route.Address,
                            City = route.City,
                            PostalCode = route.PostalCode,
                            Country = route.Country,
                            DestinationName = route.DestinationName,
                            Carrier = route.Carrier,
                            Loads = route.Loads

                        }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

An this is the View:

```
<Window x:Class="TOP2.Views.PlanningWindow"       
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TOP2.Views"
        Title="{DynamicResource planningTitle}" Height="768" Width="1080" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Icon="Images/truck.ico" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">


            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="738" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1078">

                                <Button x:Name="addTruckBtn" Content="{DynamicResource addTruckBtn}"  Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="32" Width="93" />
                <Button x:Name="addLoadBtn" Content="{DynamicResource addLoadBtn}" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="65" Width="93" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="routesCmbx" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="32" Width="127" ItemsSource="{Binding RoutesCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Code"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnexport" Canvas.Left="1019" Canvas.Top="692" Width="46" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.4,0.364"  Height="46">
                    <Image Source="Images/excel.png" Stretch="None" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnprint" Canvas.Left="958" Canvas.Top="692" Width="46" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.4,0.364" Height="46">
                    <Image Source="Images/printer.png" Stretch="None" />
                </Button>
            </Canvas>        
</Window>
```

The DataContext is assigned externally. I don't need to update or edit the items, only select one. Anybody knows what is happening?

**Update:**

This is the applied style, seems that the error is here:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}"/>
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="FocusedOn">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="FocusedOff">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                            <TextBox Visibility="Hidden" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Margin="-1" Stroke="{StaticResource selectedStroke}" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextBoxNorm}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1,1,3,3">
                                        <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">

                                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>

                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FocusedOff}" x:Name="FocusedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FocusedOn}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="95" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="AllowsTransparency" SourceName="Popup" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="ContentSite"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>

        <Style d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.73"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOn">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.84"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOff">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver" Fill="{StaticResource hoverGradient}" Stroke="{StaticResource hoverStroke}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"  Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelected" Fill="{StaticResource BtnOverFill}" Stroke="{StaticResource selectedStroke}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundHighlight" Margin="1" Stroke="#A0FFFFFF" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}" x:Name="HoverOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOff}" x:Name="SelectedOff_BeginStoryboard1"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOn}" x:Name="SelectedOn_BeginStoryboard1"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: It looks like your comboboxitem template is custom. Can you post the relevant XAML of the Style / Template?

Comment: Hi @HighCore, thank you for your response. I edited the XAML, now Is showed the whole code.

Comment: I mean the `Styles` and `Templates`.

Comment: The applied style is "WhistlerBlue", a standard style provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Remove the style and see if it helps.

Comment: WOW! Now is showed correctly! So the fail is in the style...

Comment: Post the XAML of the style and template for the `ComboBoxItem`, maybe I can find the error.

Comment: Hi again HighCore, I just edited my post and attached the template. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use "WhistlerBlue" style you should define `ItemTemplate`:

```
...
    <ComboBox x:Name="routesCmbx" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="32" Width="127" ItemsSource="{Binding RoutesCollection}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
...
```